# Router with OpenVPN client and TP-link like bandwidth control

Tags: router

I like my Asus router RT-ac59u, because of the openVPN feature. To be more specific, I use the VPN as client. not Server.

But I have a tp-link that deals better with quotas.

In Asus you can limit quota per device (bandwidth - not auto) fig 1; or use auto. quota (QoS), but it is not per device, it its per usage type (download etc. [in some routers this has two branches traditional or Adaptive QoS ]). So it simply does not work well for several devices (fig 2). (those two modes [Bandwidth vs QoS] do not work at the same time) [asus emulator](http://demoui.asus.com/QoS_EZQoS.asp),   [QoS](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1010951/)

So, the Asus has quotas per device (Bandwidth), but they do not adapt to the current situation (number of active devices, etc) (fig 1), or, the automatic system (QoS) that does not work well (one device can get most of the bandwidth in practice) (fig 2).

In tp-link, by contrast, you set a min. and max. for any or all devices (IPs), and it guarantees you an uniform distribution of your bandwidth. But I have not OpenVpn in that router. (fig 3) [tp-link emulator](https://emulator.tp-link.com/Emulator_TL-WR841NV14(US)/index.htm)

Anyone knows a model with both characteristics (tp-link quota and openvpn as client)? The tp-link Archer AX1500 won't work. Does not have VPN (Openvpn) as Client, only server.

Related post: https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/168500

#### Figure 1. Asus per device (Bandwidth limiter). If only one device, it would be unnecessarily limited

[image]

#### Figure 2. Asus per type (traditional or adaptive QoS). If several devices, one of them can monopolize most of the bandwidth

[image]

#### Figure 3. TP-Link. Min. and Max. limits, works better for several devices (in my small bandwidth)

[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to flash your router with OpenWRT but if you want this out of the box, you will need to look into something like Ubiquity.

Comment: thx, I dont think there is opernwrt for ac59u. in addition, versions of hardware must match exactly, and there are several hardware versions per model.